# Graphical Bug In Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, graphics-card

I am experiencing this graphical bug ( Lines between blocks) in my game.
My GPU : GeForce 940MX

[image]

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurred because my Anti Aliasing was turned to 4x on Nvidia Control Panel. It had to be change to Application control and now the textures are smooth without any lines. Bingo!